# Sketch 'Resize to Fit' is disabled but my content still gets resized

Tags: sketch-app, resize

I have a symbol with text + an arrow and resize to fit is disabled however when I resize it the arrow still gets messed up, am I missing something / doing something wrong??

***Symbols Page***
[image: 01]

***The Symbol in an artboard***
[image: 02]

***The symbol being resized (raster arrow)***
[image: 03]

***The symbol being resized (vector arrow)***
[image: 03]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You'll want to do two things:

[image: Text resizing]

1. Set the text to be pinned to the top and left within the `Resizing` section of the right-hand inspector pane.

[image: Triangle resizing]

2. Then set the triangle to be pinned to the top and right, and enable `Fix Width` and `Fix Height`. This will ensure it stays the same height and width, no matter the size of your symbol.

---

### The Result

[image: Resizing without distortion]

A symbol that can be resized to any size you'd like and the triangle will stay the same size, shape, and absolute position relative to the symbol's dimensions.

---

### But what if …

But what if you need another dropdown with a different size text and triangle?

Well, you can either:

1. Create a new symbol of a different size. You could keep the arrow the same size and make the text smaller (or visa versa).

[image: Scale option in Sketch]

2. Or use the same symbol and use the `Scale` option (and only the scale option). Adjusting the height and width manually won't scale things appropriately. That said, the text and the arrow will be scaled down at the same ratio — which might not be what you're looking for.